# Understanding the statistical significance calculated in an experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, p-value, inference

I am trying to understand analysis in a paper which talks about statistical significance of a certain stimulus. I have used 'VALUE' in place of the specific variable that is being observed, and 'STIMULUS' to represent experimental stimulus on the experiment group that may influence the VALUE people get. The following is what it says:

> We ﬁnd that 89% of those who got their VALUE increased were given the
>   STIMULUS (experiment group), compared to 64% who did not get the
>   VALUE increased. This diﬀerence is signiﬁcant (p=.000065, χ2=16.02), and
>   suggests that STIMULUS impacts the VALUE people get.

I would like to understand how the author has calculated the significance. What kind of significance test is this?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a test based on a statistic assumed to have a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom under the null, asymptotically at least; & the description makes it clear two counted proportions are being compared. Wald, score, & likelihood-ratio tests are all possibilities; [Pearson's chi-squared test for homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence) is the most popular (& Yates' correction may or may not have been used).

Asymptotically these tests are equivalent—in this case the information given suggests sample sizes sufficiently large that any difference in the p-values got by using one or the other would be unimportant for most purposes.